# Running an ECS scheduled task on demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs

This may get shut down for being opinion based but here goes anyway..

I have some scheduled tasks setup in ECS to run once a day, but I want to be able to trigger them based on a user action too, for example an admin clicking a button in our app to kick off one of the scheduled tasks when needed sooner than the normal scheduled time.

How could this be achieved? I'm thinking of an API gateway endpoint which uses a lamba which uses the runtask function from aws-cli. This seems overly complicated as you have to define the whole task, when I just want to "run job named x now" but I'm not sure that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EventBridge Schedule to run tasks on schedule, and an API gateway endpoint to run tasks from the admin panel.

> I'm thinking of an API gateway endpoint which uses a lamba which uses the runtask function from aws-cli.

You don't need Lambda for that, not to mention aws-cli. API gateway allows creating native integrations with almost any AWS service. If your admin button passes any complex parameters, you'll need to create a mapping template to map these parameters to your task parameters.

One possible problem is that both the schedule and the button will fire the task right away. If concurrent invocation of two tasks is a problem, you might want to submit a job to a Batch queue rather than firing it right away.

> as you have to define the whole task, when I just want to "run job named x now"

I'm not sure how these two are opposite. To run a job named X, you need to define the job named X first. You do just that by creating a [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html), and then to run the task you just provide the ARN of this definition as a parameter to `RunTask` or `SubmitJob`.

Comment: was looking into using the API gateway integration but from this page it doesnt seem to have first class integration with the ecs apis? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services-reference.html

Comment: @Omiron: you're looking at a feature for HTTP apis. In a REST api, you define the integration with (almost) any AWS service action, and set up a mapping template to translate between your endpoint parameters and the request body and parameters that the AWS action expects.